# Prevent Screen Saver From Appearing on Android TV

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-tv, screensaver

I have a product that is a web app running on android wrapped app on TVs.
Over time the app is timing out and going to screen saver.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startWebview();
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        generateUniqueIdentifier();

    }
```

I have added             **getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);**
but screen saver still appears

Also in

```
  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        if (mWebView != null) {
            mWebView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }

    }
```

Is there a way to stop the screen saver from going on?

Comment: lonut, Is it not working with specific android device or API level?

Comment: @Harshali It' not working for any android device

Comment: Try with xml file, add `android:keepScreenOn="true"` in your activity_main xml file.

Comment: @Harshali I am also using a WebView, I guess I also need `mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setKeepScreenOn(true);`

Comment: Does it works? set `setKeepScreenOn` to webView keep your screen on?